# A stop job is running for session c1 of user gdm after installing nVidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I recently installed a 1050 Ti on my pc, and used the driver recommended from the Additional drivers submenu in the settings. (375)

After that, my boot and shutdown screens got messed up (low resolution, bad graphics) and my shutdown times got increased.

I removed plymouth, since I wasn't going to fix the issue with it looking crappy and now I have access to the logging that's being done during startup and shutdown. During shutdown (especially after long sessions) I see this.

`A stop job is running for session c1 of user gdm (0s/1m 30s)`

I tried everything (literally) to fix it. The only solutions I have found are to manually change the 90s delay to something less or to install watchdog. I find both a bit bad.

AFAIK, if it needs to shutdown something there in the first place, it wasn't properly shut when it should have, and now the system waits for it to exit before forcing it to...

All I fear is to harm my hardware or my data. I don't want the normal shutdown procedure to cause problems and that's why I don't like to mess with it.

Oh, I am Using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3

**EDIT: 18/7/2019**

I am editing this almost two years later, to say that the **SOLUTION** I found then, was changing from GDM to LightDM. It fixed the issue immediately and I never returned to GDM. I use Mint 19.1 atm, which also has LightDM, so I cannot comment on the status of GDM with this issue.

Comment: Read thru read, address as you see fit. As far as the 90 default time out. It's too long & lowering the time is not "bad"  At least here I've never seen any of the couple of instances same or similar actually do anything but time out. So if that's the case the time of the timeout is irrelevant.. Here on an ssd I use 10 sec's, in an launchpad bug dev's suggested they should have adjusted it to 30 sec. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1615

Answer (score 1):

When searching about gdm, I came across the configure of gdm on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which seems to fix my problem of the message
`A stop job is running for session c1 of user gdm (0s/1m 30s)`

The command is as following:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`