# How to dermine why a systemd service is not stopping on shutdown? (stop job is running)

Tags: 22.04, systemd, reboot, gdm

Recently every time I shut down or reboot my laptop, it is slow to shut down, and shows the following message:

[image]

```
A stop job is running for Session c1 of User gdm
```

I tried several similar questions that mention installing `watchdog` or reconfiguring `dgm3`, but they don't seem to work in my case.

Some answers suggest setting `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` but this doesn't seem to solve the root of the problem, in the sense that the service should be able to stop in timely manner.

My questions is how to determine why the stop job is failing to stop the service, and how can I correct it sow the computer can shut down quickly as it used to?

---

With the help of @steeldriver I was able to get a log of the shutdown procedure, but I am still not able to figure out how to fix it.

```
[  308.828908] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991943.886:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=7631 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" f>
[  308.829327] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991943.886:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=7631 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" f>
[  309.222571] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.278:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.223009] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.278:87): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.223924] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.278:88): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.224330] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.282:89): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.224340] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.282:90): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.224347] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.282:91): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.224360] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.282:92): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  309.224389] audit: type=1400 audit(1678991944.282:93): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=7706 comm="firefox" requested_mask=>
[  335.174797] kauditd_printk_skb: 5 callbacks suppressed
[  335.174800] audit: type=1107 audit(1678991970.224:99): pid=1311 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop>
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  388.635030] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  389.810597] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)

[  389.810631] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_OSC]

[  389.810636] Initialized Arguments for Method [_OSC]:  (4 arguments defined for method invocation)
[  389.810639]   Arg0:   00000000773fb10f <Obj>           Buffer(16) 5D A8 3B B2 B7 C8 42 35
[  389.810662]   Arg1:   0000000038c2bc32 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[  389.810673]   Arg2:   000000005d327c75 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[  389.810681]   Arg3:   00000000f7ca0178 <Obj>           Buffer(8) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

[  389.810704] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
[  479.161836] r8169 0000:39:00.0 enp57s0: Link is Down
[  479.206104] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 60:ce:86:8f:5c:3b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  479.570797] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): unmounting filesystem.
[  479.845965] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[  479.862264] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[  479.864884] systemd-journald[820]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[  479.895325] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[  479.899820] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[  479.900966] [8762]: Remounting '/' read-only in with options 'errors=remount-ro,stripe=32'.
[  480.202152] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Quota mode: none.
[  480.300538] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[  480.300543] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[  480.300594] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
[  480.300596] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[  480.302311] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
[  480.302313] systemd-shutdown[1]: Stopping MD devices.
[  480.302379] systemd-shutdown[1]: All MD devices stopped.
[  480.302381] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[  480.302661] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM /dev/dm-2 (253:2).
[  480.345817] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM /dev/dm-0 (253:0).
[  480.346518] systemd-shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-0: Device or resource busy
[  480.346524] systemd-shutdown[1]: Not all DM devices detached, 2 left.
[  480.346777] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[  480.347377] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM /dev/dm-0 (253:0).
[  480.347912] systemd-shutdown[1]: Could not detach DM /dev/dm-0: Device or resource busy
[  480.347917] systemd-shutdown[1]: Not all DM devices detached, 2 left.
[  480.347922] systemd-shutdown[1]: Cannot finalize remaining DM devices, continuing.
[  480.360045] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Quota mode: none.
```

---

With the help of @RobertRiedl I think I was able to track down the problematic service to `session-c1.scope`. Here is the relevant output:

```
Μαρ 22 21:44:07 idefix systemd[1]: Stopping Session c1 of User gdm...
Μαρ 22 21:45:37 idefix systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.
Μαρ 22 21:45:37 idefix systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 2431 (speech-dispatch) with signal SIGKILL.
Μαρ 22 21:45:37 idefix systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Killing process 2440 (threaded-ml) with signal SIGKILL.
Μαρ 22 21:45:37 idefix systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Μαρ 22 21:45:37 idefix systemd[1]: Stopped Session c1 of User gdm.
Μαρ 22 21:45:37 idefix systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Consumed 5.879s CPU time.
```

Comment: There are some suggestions here [Diagnosing Shutdown Problems](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#diagnosingshutdownproblems), but I can't vouch for them personally

Comment: unless we know which job is running in a timeout, we can't help. [this seems to be a good place to start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496563)

Comment: @RobertRiedl: Thank you for the pointer I made an edit to the question. I actually tried that answer but couldn't find anything initially because the `--boot=-1` wasn't mentioned. I still don't know how to fix the problem though, does this information give you any ideas?

Comment: Relating a 2017 AU question: https://askubuntu.com/q/953246/619216

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Yes, I saw that question too, but the answer didn't fix the problem in my case.

Comment: can you reproduce this ? are always the same processes (speech-dispatch and threaded-ml) affected ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl: Yes it always freezes, then messages are almost the same, this time a line was added `session-c1.scope: Killing process 2682 (gmain) with signal SIGKILL.` in addition to the other two.

Comment: it looks to me like something in your gnome is holding the session open, something that utilizes the  `speech-dispatcher` which could be a lot of things, unfortunately .. oyu are on 22.04 with the latest kernel updates and so on ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl: Yes everything is updated on Ubuntu 22.04, with kernel `5.19.0-35-generic`.